# BufferedWritter-like from java on swift?

Tags: java, ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, bufferedwriter

this a java code I made a few days ago,

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        final Window parentWindow = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(EntreeElimJPanel.this);

        try{

            File file = new File("file.txt");
            file.createNewFile();
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file);
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write("Identifiant: ");
            bw.write(textField.getText());
            bw.write("\n");
            bw.write("Pass: ");
            bw.write(textField_1.getText());
            bw.flush();

            FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);


            br.close();
            bw.close();

            }catch(IOException e1){
            e1.printStackTrace();
            }
     }
```

This code write some datas on a little text file. It works fine.

I'm trying to perform the same with swift. Basically I have tried to follow some tutorials on `NSUserDefaults`, like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aMu11FJ_uDs.
I don't know why but it doesn't work. Isn't it possible to do the same thing I did on java with Swift code? am I missing something?

I just need to do precisely the same thing, save an user name/password than I can retrieve later, even if the application is closed/restarted.

Any information is welcome, I'm searching from this morning and nothing is very effective...

Thank you.

fselva

pd: this is the code that doesn't work on iOS, I waster it pretty bad:

```
@IBAction func Save(sender: AnyObject) {
    NSString saveId = self.Id.text
    NSString savePass = self.Pass.text
    NSUserDefaults defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
    [defaults setObject:saveId forKey:@"Identifiant"]
    [defaults setObject:savePass forKey:@"Password"]
    [defaults synchronize]


}
```

Comment: Please, insert the actual code you have tried and does not work, so people can help you fix it.

Comment: Note: your code has possible resource leaks.  You should close the readers and writers in finally block.  If you're running with Java 7 and up, use try-with-resources.

Comment: @sharonbn the problem isn't on the java code, it's on the fact of doing the same thing, or a similar one, with swift This portion of code, with the rest of the code, works very well

Comment: The problem, @fselva is that the Java code gives bad example that you call "works fine".  other, less experienced readers will use this example in ways you did not intend....

Comment: and the code does not work very well!!.  if you get IOException before closing the readers/writers, you leave open file handlers in the OS, if this occur enough times, the JVM will crash

Comment: hum... It was just a try catch when I was creating this code, it don't return anything. I don't thing I have done something wrong. But indeed, this code is probably not perfect, to write 2 lines on a text file it's enough, more i'm not sure then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do for ios is use [Core Data](https://mytraininglms.duke-energy.com/mytrgprod/app/SYS_Login.aspx?lang=en-us&RU=https%3A//mytraininglms.duke-energy.com/mytrgprod/app/management/LMS_ActDetails.aspx%3FActivityId%3D179632%26UserMode%3D0) but sometimes the apple docs are hard to read so heres a good tutorial about [it](http://jamesonquave.com/blog/core-data-in-swift-tutorial-part-1/)

Comment: I would make a data model of username password and its easier to retrieve and store it using core data.

Comment: It is indeed what the tutorial seems to say, I'm reading it and trying it. I accept your answer, I think it's a good way for me to perform what I aim